# How to switch tabs while page is loading, selenium with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webautomation

I am currently creating a project where I want to open the same page many times repetitively in different tabs. The problem I am facing is that when I do this I get stuck waiting for the page to load before I can open it in a new tab.

The desired end result would be that I would not have to wait for the page to finish loading before I go to fetch the additional pages in other tabs.

Currently the approach looks something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)    
driver.get('mysite.com')
for i in range(10):
     driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
     driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i+1])
     driver.get('mysite.com')
```

When this runs now it loads the page and waits for the page to finish loading before moving to the next page. Instead I want it to wait 1 second (the page_load_timeout) and immediately open a new tab and fetch the website.

Anyway to achieve my desired result using python 3.7 with selenium and chrome?

Thank you!

Comment: why can't you just pass the site name as part of your js step `driver.execute_script("window.open('mysite.com');")` without switching to the new window directly.

Comment: If this works then I write it as answer and I will approve :)